# Backbone.js - passing arguments through constructors

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

**Scenario:**
I got an `alert()` saying `undefined` when I (try to) set the `myVar` variable through the Constructor. However if I uncomment the `myVar` that's living inside the myView, the alert then instead says "Hello from inside", just as one would expect.

**Question:**
Does this mean that I cannot set any params in the constructor of the view except backbones own params, such as `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className` & `tagName`?
*Manual: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor*

**The code:**

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

    //myVar : 'Hello from inside',

    initialize: function() {
        alert(this.myVar);
    }
)};

new myView({myVar: 'Hello from outside'});
```

Comment: The accepted answer is INCORRECT. The answer from Brave Dave is correct (backbone has changed). Please downvote the accepted answer and upvote the one from Dave to show correct answer above,

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Options passed into the constructor are automatically stored as `this.options`

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

  myVar : 'Hello from inside',

  initialize: function() {
      alert(this.options.myVar);
  }
)};

new myView({myVar: 'Hello from outside'});
```

Comment: It should be noted that in this situation your newly created view will have `this.myVar` and `this.options.myVar`. If you're trying to overwrite `this.myVar` with options passed you may want to `this.myVar=this.options.myVar` in your initialize function.

Comment: Awesome!  Quick find from Google.

Comment: Still Awesome quick & simple post in 2013 ! Thanks ^^

Comment: alternatively store `myVar` on an options object: `options: { myVar : 'Hello from inside' },`. The options will automatically be merged, and be available on `this.options`

Comment: This answer, as for now, is INCORRECT.  See the answer from Brave Dave to save yourself hurdle.

Answer (score 28):

As of backbone 1.1.0, the `options` argument is [no longer attached](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog) automatically to the view (see [issue 2458](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2458) for discussion). You now need to attach the options of each view manually:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        _.extend(this, _.pick(options, "myVar", ...));
        // options.myVar is now at this.myVar
    }
});

new MyView({
    myVar: "Hello from outside"
    ...
});
```

Alternatively you can use [this mini plugin](https://github.com/rotundasoftware/backbone.viewOptions) to auto-attach white-listed options, like so:

```
MyView = BaseView.extend({
    options : ["myVar", ...] // options.myVar will be copied to this.myVar on initialize
});
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer.