# Send extra params to a view on backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was trying the solutions that suggest in this questions but it don't work

[How to pass parameters to a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803138/backbone-js-how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-view)

[How can I pass a parameter into a Backbone.js view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561022/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-into-a-backbone-js-view)

[Backbone.js - passing arguments through constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463537/backbone-js-passing-arguments-through-constructors)

I am trying to pass extra parameter to use in my template, I read that all extra params that I pass I can have access to them in `this.options.varName` but it dont work for me.

heres the controller code:

```
servicios : function(){
    //Crea la colecion de tipos de servicios municipales

    //Crea el modelo para dar de alta un nuevo reporte de servicio municipal
    var reporteServicioSingle = new ReporteServicioSingle();

    //Crea la vista para la pantalla de servicios municipales
    var servicios_view = new Servicios({
        model      : reporteServicioSingle,
        collection : this.reportes,
        tipos      : this.tipos
    });

    // Carga la vista renderisada y inicializa foundation
    $("#app-content").html(servicios_view.render().el);
    $(document).foundation();
},
```

And this is my view code:

```
render: function(){
    console.log(this.options.tipos);
    this.$el.html(Handlebars.templates.servicios(this.collection));
    $(document).foundation();
    return this;
},
```

but the chrome developers console, send me an error that options is not definided.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tipos' of undefined
```

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Backbone 1.1.0 Views - Passing Options](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19325323/722238).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Backbone 1.1, it no longer attaches the `options` argument to `this.options` automatically anymore, a shitty change (imho).

You'll need to extend the options parameter yourself in your initialization method:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = _.omit(options, ['model', 'collection', 'el', 'id', 'attributes', 'className', 'tagName', 'events']);
}
```

Comment: Why not pull out precisely the options your view needs so that your view's interface is at least specified in one place?

Comment: ...because that would be terrible for maintainability?

Comment: A well specified interface is terrible for maintainability? What? Not knowing an object's interface is terrible for maintainability.

Comment: @muistooshort ¿What that you mean with pull out the options?

Comment: @kentverger He means rather than extending everything from the `options` parameter, to only pick out what you intend to use. My guess is he a programmer used to a strongly typed language. However, convention with Javascript is to not create rigid interfaces (hence the complete lack of interfaces).